# Resolving "proposal response was not successful" error in Hyperledger Fabric tutorial

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am running the Fabric sample 'fabcar' following [this tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html#launch-the-network).

After running the `startFabric.sh javascript` command, I am getting this error:

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting chaincode fabcar:1.0 for transaction

```
 ubuntu@testvm1:~/fabric-samples/fabcar$ ./startFabric.sh javascript

    # don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
    export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
    Removing network net_basic
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com 
    orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com couchdb
    Creating ca.example.com ... done
    Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
    Creating orderer.example.com ...
    Creating ca.example.com ...
    Creating peer0.org1.example.com ...
    # wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
    # incase of errors when running later commands, issue export 
    FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
    export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
    #echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
    sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
    # Create the channel
    docker exec -e 
 "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP"e"CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp 
    /users/Admin@org1.example.com/ms 
    p" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 
    -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
    2019-03-29 10:29:37.993 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 
    Endorser and orderer connections initialized
    2019-03-29 10:29:38.034 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Received 
    block: 0
    # Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
    docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e 
 "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/m 
    sp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
    2019-03-29 10:29:38.267 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 
    Endorser and orderer connections initialized
    2019-03-29 10:29:38.459 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 002 
    Successfully submitted proposal to join channel
    Creating cli ... done
    2019-03-29 10:29:39.729 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> 
    INFO 001 Using default escc
    2019-03-29 10:29:39.729 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> 
    INFO 002 Using default vscc
    2019-03-29 10:29:39.767 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> INFO 003 Installed 
    remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" >
    2019-03-29 10:29:39.982 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> 
    INFO 001 Using default escc
    2019-03-29 10:29:39.982 UTC [chaincodeCmd] check`enter code 
    here`ChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
    Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not 
    successful, error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting chaincode 
    fabcar:1.0 for transaction
```